# Как убрать дефолтную сортировку по первому столбцу?

Tags: javascript, datatable

Если инициализировать плагин *Datatables*, то по дефолту он сортирует данные по первому столбцу

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
        </tr>           
    </tbody>        
</table>
```

Как отключить данную сортировку, чтобы данные выстраивались именно в той последовательности, в которой был произведён рендеринг данных или передан массив с данными?

Answer (score 1):

Для старых версий (<1.10) необходимо установить у поля "aaSorting" значение пустого массива:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        /* Отключение сортировки при инициализации */
        "aaSorting": []
    });
})
```

Для более новых версий (>= 1.10) использовать поле [order](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        /* Никакой сортировки во время инициализации */
        "order": []
    });
})
```